# User to user app request doesn't appear in notifications

Tags: facebook, apprequests, fb.ui

This is very weird. I know that if you create app to user created app-request, it doesn't appear anywhere..

but in this case I tried the FB.ui dialog to create user to user app request. Like this:

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'I invite you for a coffee together',
    to: xxxxxxxx
});
```

It opens the dialog and sends the request successfully.

but the problem is that the recipient doesnt get notified about the app request in any way..

I tried disabling sandbox mode and everything, but there's no way to notify the recipient about the apprequest he has received :/

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I am having that same issu, did you end up resolving it?

Answer (score 4):

besides Juicy's tip, one known problem with apprequests they only work with canvas apps.

so even if your app is a website or just an tab, without an canvas (app on facebook) the request is never displayed. you will have to add some code on the canvas url to redirect the user to the right place when the user is accepting the request.

Also be aware if you use the new auth modal dialog and authenticated refferals the accepting user gets an error when he wants to accept the request. see http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/191961117570028

Comment: Exactly. So if anybody has a tab app and requires app requests: Add a canvas app in the app settings and point it to a simple page that reads the request_ids parameter and redirects via JavaScript to the tab app URL with the request_ids passed in some way in the app_data parameter of the tab URL.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the request is sent while your app with sandbox disabled. If it was sent while app was in sandbox mode this request will not be shown event if sandbox will be disabled.

It's important to note that changes to application settings may be not immediate and you need to wait a couple of mins (no need to wait hours for that!) after disabling sandbox mode.

In case you still fail to see the requests by a user in notifications that was sent from another user in a public application, file a bug using [Facebook Bug tool](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create).